# Исправить ошибку CF7 путем хитрости через jquery, как осуществить?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form7

Добрый день саму ошибку я не знаю как исправить уже пытались и переделывали форму несколько раз content type и тд. Но другой тест показал что ошибки нету в nginx но этот серв на апаче и тут вот такая ошибка. 
Поэтому я хочу обойти ее так как не могу ничего сделать с сервером(
Ошибка в форме отправке вечно грузится но сообщения уходят!
Как сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки после сабмита закрывался мой попап который снизу справа находится и вылазило другое окно ваше сообщение мол успешно ушло)?
http://bilim.astana.kz/ru/test-2/

Comment: Последние версии плагина CF7 часто конфликтуют с другими скриптами на сайте. Поставьте версию 4.7

Comment: К сожалению не помогло)

Comment: С попапом вашим это проблему не решит ) Только с бесконечным вращением значка отправки сообщений